# How to load multiple csv files (different schemas) into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 6,500 csv files with ~250 different schema's. i.e. These files are from the F.D.I.C (USA bank regulator) dataset. They have been uploaded to a google cloud storage bucket: 
[image]

Each financial quarter has ~250 different csv's. Each csv, within a financial quarter, has a different schema: 
[image]

There are ~250 unique schemas. The schema's repeat themselves, each financial quarter. The csv files go back 100 financial quarters to 1992:
[image]

Multiple CSV's,with the same schema, can be uploaded using a wild card. e.g. `gs/path/*.csv`. However each table name is not being auto generated from the file name. The UI requires a table name as an input: 
[image]

How does one load multiple csv files with different schemas into bigquery?

Comment: You'd have to use `bq` command line tool to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would go about automating this is basically reading all the files from a given bucket (or its subfolder) and (making an assumption) using their "filename" to be the target tablename to ingest. Here is how:

```
gsutil ls gs://mybucket/subfolder/*.csv | xargs -I{} echo {} | awk '{n=split($1,A,"/"); q=split(A[n],B,"."); print "mydataset."B[1]" "$0}' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'bq --location=US load --replace=false --autodetect --source_format=CSV {}'
```

Make sure to replace `location`, `mydataset` with your desired values. Also, please take note of the following assumptions:

- First row of each CSV is assumed to be the header, and thus is treated as column names.
- We are writing with `--replace=false` flag, meaning data will be appended everytime you run the command. If you want to overwrite instead, just turn it to `true` and all tables' data will be over-written on each run.
- CSV filenames (part before `.csv` is used as a tablename. You can modify the awk script to change it to any other alternative.

Comment: You have to run it in the command line, with `gsutil` installed.

Comment: You have to install `gsutil`, `bq` command line tools locally on your computer, or on your vm. Please google "gsutil command line tool install" and "bq command line tool install" to see details of how you can install and utilize these.