# Recursively go through folders and load the csv files in each folder into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have Google Cloud Storage Bucket which follows this style of directory:

```
gs://mybucket/{year}/{month}/{day}/{a csv file here}
```

The csv files all follow the same schema so it shouldn't be an issue. I was wondering if there was a easier method of loading all the files in 1 command or even a cloud function into 1 table in BigQuery. I've been using *bl load* to accomplish this for now, but seeing that I have to do this about every week, I'd like to get some automation for it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652651/how-to-load-multiple-csv-files-different-schemas-into-bigquery)

You can recursively load your files with the following command:

```
gsutil ls gs://mybucket/**.csv | \
    xargs -I{} echo {} | \
    awk -F'[/.]' '{print "yourdataset."$7"_"$4"_"$5"_"$6" "$0}' | \
    xargs -I{} sh -c 'bq --location=YOUR_LOCATION load --replace=false --autodetect --source_format=CSV {}'
```

This loads your CSV files into independant tables in your target dataset, with the naming convention "filename_year_month_day".
The "recursively" part is ensured by the double wildcard (**).

This is for the manual part..

For the automation part you have the choice between different options:

- the easiest one is probably to associate a Cloud Function that you trigger with Cloud Scheduler. There is no bash runtime available so you would for instance have to Python your way through. [Here](https://medium.com/@asajharland/effective-data-loading-with-bigquery-batch-loading-flat-files-bf2fd0ebb325) is what a quick Google search gave me.
- it is possible to do that with an orchestrator (Cloud Composer) if you have the infrastructure (if you don't, don't consider)
- another solution is to use Cloud Run, triggered either by Cloud Scheduler (on regular occasions then), or through Eventarc triggers when your csv files are uploaded to GCS.

Comment: For a cloud function, would I just kind of loop through the folders in python. Im pretty new to cloud functions, so I'll definetly need some guidance on setting up triggers and such. Right now, Im currently running a cron task on a Compute engine to migrate data, so I was thinking that the success from that should be able to be used as a trigger right?

Comment: This is a different question than the post. You should maybe open a new question for this.  If the given answer fits your needs, you can accept the answer and then ask your next question (with a few more details on what your cron job does).

Comment: To answer shortly, to trigger a Cloud function is simply to send an HTTP request to the function endpoint