# how to force bigquery to load csv file all column as string without schema and autodetect=False

Tags: google-bigquery

I have multiple csv files stored in gcs, I want to load them to bigquery using cloud run.

The problem I don't know the schema and the schema is variable always change also  I don't want to use autodetect option when load files.
I want to load csv files to bigquery using bigquery api loadconfig without schema and autodetect=False, all columns considered of type string.

is that possible ?

I tried to use pandas dataframe , but files are too large so always there is memory problems.

Comment: While loading a csv file into BigQuery, you can skip giving schema and also give autodetect=false in BigQuery API.It is not possible in BigQuery to directly load the data in BigQuery empty table without schema. You can load multiple csv files with variable schema but for that I would recommend you to use [autodetect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect) schema. You can refer to this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67512880/load-multiple-csv-from-google-cloud-storage-to-multiple-table-in-bigquery) for your requirement. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to generate schema with all columns as STRING type.

```
def getschema(file_path):
'''Get schema from CSV with all columns as string'''
schema = []
with open(file_path, 'r') as read_obj:
    # pass the file object to DictReader() to get the DictReader object
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    # get column names from a csv file
    column_names = csv_dict_reader.fieldnames
for c in column_names:
    schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(c,"STRING"))
return schema
```